# Pandas processing getting killed

Tags: python, pandas, out-of-memory

I'm trying to process a folder with ~100000 images. They are named based on their ids. I want to create pairs of images representing the same asset to further train a siamese net. I'm using pandas for this. My idea is to create groups, perform cross joins and generate pairs. I've tried all approaches I could think of. The latest one is saving each piece of data for further processing. However, the process still gets killed. I'm assuming this is due to a memory error. I keep watching the process and the RAN usage goes from 9 to 16 GB (all my RAM) abruptly.

[image]

I'm not sure what else I can do to get this running:

```
"""
Used to generate positive and negative pairs.
"""

import logging
import math
import os
from multiprocessing import Pool
from typing import Tuple
import tempfile

import glob
import pandas as pd
from data_generation.utils import images_to_df, save_df
from tqdm import tqdm

pd.set_option("display.max_columns", None)
pd.set_option("display.max_rows", None)
pd.set_option("display.max_colwidth", None)


class PairGenerator:
    def __init__(self, root_dir: str):
        """
        Initializes the pair generator pipeline.

        Args:
            root_dir: base directory in which to look for jpg images.
        """
        self._root_dir: str = root_dir
        self._pool: Pool = Pool(os.cpu_count() - 1)
        self._images_df: pd.DataFrame = images_to_df(self._root_dir)
        self._samples_per_group: int = (
            5  # Restricting the number of samples or we will have a huge dataset
        )
        self._temp_dir = tempfile.mkdtemp()
        logging.info(f"Temporary dir created at: {self._temp_dir}>")

    def generate_pairs(self) -> None:
        """
        Generates pairs of positive and negative samples.
        Saves the output as csv.
        """
        self.generate_positive_pairs()

    def generate_positive_pairs(self) -> None:
        """
        Generates a data frame containing positive pairs.

        Returns:
            Data frame with positive pairs.
        """
        grouped = self._images_df.groupby(by=["site_id", "img_id"])
        logging.info(
            f"Found {len(grouped)} groups. Average of {len(self._images_df) / len(grouped)} images per car."
        )

        for group_name, group in tqdm(grouped, total=len(grouped)):
            save_df(group, os.path.join(*[self._temp_dir, f"{'_'.join(group_name)}.csv"]))

        for group_name in tqdm(glob.glob(self._temp_dir + "/*.csv")):
            group = pd.read_csv(group_name)
            self.merge_positive(group_name, group)

        # results = self._pool.starmap(
        #     self.merge_positive, tqdm(grouped, total=len(grouped))
        # )

    def merge_positive(self, _: str, group: pd.DataFrame) -> None:
        """
        Given a grouped data frame containing images of the same car,
        performs a cross join to generate positive samples.

        Args:
            _: unused, group name.
            group: data frame grouped by site_id and img_id.
        Returns:
            Data frame with the columns `img_path_x` and `img_path_y`,
                representing a positive pair, i.e., the images have the same @img_id.
        """
        group = group.drop(columns=["img_name", "site_id", "img_id"])
        group_merge = group.merge(group, how="cross")
        group_merge = group_merge[
            group_merge["img_path_x"] != group_merge["img_path_y"]
        ]
        group_merge = group_merge[
            ~group_merge[["img_path_x", "img_path_y"]]
            .apply(frozenset, axis=1)
            .duplicated()
        ]
        group_merge = group_merge.sample(n=min(len(group_merge), self._samples_per_group))

        save_df(group_merge, os.path.join(self._root_dir, "positive.csv"), 'a+', index=False)
```

Comment: You most likely are getting a kind invitation to begin using pyspark. This does parrallel processing. The beauty is, you can wrap your code into a pandas udf https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/udf-python-pandas.html

Comment: do you have control over process partitioning in dask, like you do in pyspark?
 this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61920105/dask-applying-a-function-over-a-large-dataframe-which-is-more-than-ram