# Dask worker failure(s) with value_counts()

Tags: python, bigdata, dask

In the first stage of my pipeline I've converted a load of .csvs into parquette files using dask, which total about 6gb output (~60gb csvs, but some fields get dropped/converted into more efficient dtypes). This is approx. 360m rows of data; probably just a bit too much for pandas to handle.

In the second stage, I want to filter this dask dataframe for only values which are seen more than once. I first define a LocalCluster (48gb RAM locally):

```
cluster = LocalCluster(
n_workers=1,
processes=True,
threads_per_worker=1,
memory_limit='42GB'
)
```

And then run something akin to:

```
ddf_filter = ddf['UID'].value_counts().map(lambda x: x > 1)
ddf = ddf[ddf["UID"].isin(list(ddf_filter[ddf_filter].index))]
```

But this invariably results in any one of a number of error messages, regardless of how many different choices of memory or n_workers that I have.

**Update**: I can get the code to run past the above stage, but it now fails on this computationally expensive groupby:

```
ddf = ddf.groupby('UID').agg(list).compute()
```

Is there something I should be changing in my dask .yaml files?

I appreciate that these are not quick tasks to ask of dask, but I expected it to perhaps be able to write to disk and handle memory in a way that -- even if slow -- would still complete. I've tried on different machines, and with different settings.

My `pipreqs .` looks like:

```
numpy==1.24.2
pandas==1.0.5
tqdm==4.64.1
dask==2023.3.2
pyreadr==0.4.7
```

The error messages are as follows. First a few pages of this to standard out:

> WARNING - gc.collect() took 14.757s. This is usually a sign that some
> tasks handle too many Python objects at the same time. Rechunking the
> work into smaller tasks might help. 2023-04-01 22:10:41,328 -
> distributed.worker.memory - WARNING - Worker is at 82% memory usage.
> Pausing worker.  Process memory: 32.91 GiB -- Worker memory limit:
> 40.05 GiB 2023-04-01 22:11:51,849 - distributed.worker.memory - WARNING - Unmanaged memory use is high. This may indicate a memory
> leak or the memory may not be released to the OS; see
> https://distributed.dask.org/en/latest/worker-memory.html#memory-not-released-back-to-the-os
> for more information. -- Unmanaged memory: 33.65 GiB -- Worker memory
> limit: 40.05 GiB

Then three restarts of the worker:

> 2023-04-01 22:22:24,935 - distributed.nanny.memory - WARNING - Worker
> tcp://127.0.0.1:43131 (pid=174018) exceeded 95% memory budget.
> Restarting...

then CancelledError:

> distributed.scheduler.KilledWorker: Attempted to run task
> ('aggregate-chunk-f53c95d43184b91d62d530ce4b46e08e-b0b1ec58f87899514174d2ba349d197d',
> 2) on 3 different workers, but all those workers died while running
> it.
>
> asyncio.exceptions.CancelledError

Any advice would be warmly appreciated!

Comment: What error messages are you getting? Are you sure they are all related to memory issues?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your message! They generally vary, but the main ones relate to:


1.)  >95% memory limit, worker restarting (does this restart the job?)
2.) out of memory,  worker killed (does this restart the job?)
3.) cannot overflow to disk -> stdout spam -> hang

Comment: Yeah, using >95% of the memory will restart the process, and if that happens enough times the process will get blacklisted and not run again. [Here](https://www.glennklockwood.com/data-intensive/analysis/dask.html) is a page that recommends using some kind of local scheduler. Otherwise, you may need to split up your files to get them to run like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61920105/dask-applying-a-function-over-a-large-dataframe-which-is-more-than-ram).

Comment: Hi, you should print the complete error message you get. You can also try to compute things step by step: can you get `ddf_filter = ddf['UID'].value_counts()`? How large is this?

Comment: With many thanks for your help, I updated the question above to include error messages and reflect the fact that it was actually the groupby aggregate that was failing most recently.

Comment: ddf = ddf.groupby('UID').agg(list).compute(): usung compute on a Dask dataframe, you'll convert it to a Pandas one in your main process memory, which means loading all the values into worker memory first. Do you have enough memory to do this? Else, you should probably try to write the results on disk.